# MySQL: AUTO_INCREMENT for second column based on third column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a MySQL Table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tab` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pos` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `parent` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How can i add thread safe & fast AUTO_INCREMENT for "pos" but with respect of "parent" value.

for example:

```
insert parent 1 -> id=1 / pos=1 / parent=1
insert parent 1 -> id=2 / pos=2 / parent=1
insert parent 2 -> id=3 / pos=1 / parent=2
insert parent 2 -> id=4 / pos=2 / parent=2
insert parent 1 -> id=5 / pos=3 / parent=1
```

Comment: You probably have to use a trigger for this.

Comment: I know you found a solution, but I think a `ORDER BY` could have solved your problem. `ORDER BY  parent ASC, pos ASC`

Answer (score -1):

After some searching, i found a solution, but is this the best one?

thread-safe?
fast?

Can i remove delimiter?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tab_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON tab
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.`pos` = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(pos), 0) + 1 FROM tab WHERE parent = NEW.parent);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```